# How can I add a css class to elements conditionally in django?

Tags: css, django, django-templates

I have created a template of sidebar in django which is extended by various pages.

```
 <ul class="navbar-nav flex-column mt-5">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link p-3 mb-2 text-white" href=#>
                                    <i class="fas fa-home text-white ml-2 fa-lg mr-3"></i> Dashboard
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul class="navbar-nav flex-column">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link p-3 mb-2 text-white" href="{% url 'a' %}">
                                    <i class="fas fa-briefcase text-white ml-2 fa-lg mr-3"></i> Business
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul class="navbar-nav flex-column">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link p-3 mb-2 text-white" href="#">
                                    <i class="fas fa-chart-pie text-white ml-2 fa-lg mr-3"></i> Analytics
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
```

The links shown above direct to various pages and are present in sidebar i.e the template.
I have created two css classes current and sidebar-link to show which link from the above is active and which are sidebar links. How do I conditionally apply one of these classes to these links depending upon which one is currently active?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a view for each page (Dashboard, Business, Analytics) then you only have to render different templates for each view.

**views.py**

```
def dashboard(request):
   return render(request, 'dashboard.html', {})

def business(request):
   return render(request, 'business.html', {})

def analytics(request):
   return render(request, 'analytics.html', {})
```

So you can style the templates independently

Comment: I was doing the same before. But now I am thinking about making use of the existing template and reuse the code instead of typing it again. That's why I extended a default layout(which has this sidebar) to the other pages. Is there any other way to achieve it? Perhaps using js?